# Javascript double event firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am returning a simple javascriptResult that unhides a div.  When I do this, other click events that post ajax will now post twice when clicked. What could be causing this?

Comment: the js returned can be anything ie "alert("bad post");" it doesnt matter. all the click events on the page subsequenty double post.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it will be a case of event bubbling. You can stop event bubbling by just giving return false at the end of the function that is being called.

See **[event bubbing](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)**